# CATiledLayer - how to use when async downloading images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, catiledlayer

In my application, I have got a scrollview, a bigger one with lots of subviews on it, subviews gets added dynamically based on scroll. I try to add subviews (imageviews) dynamically on scroll and when user scrolls then I try to fetch more images asynchronously based on pageSize etc from server and these images gets placed into it's corresponding imageview..

I have gone through Apple's WWDC Sessoion 104 as well which appears to be good for offline images.

I also try to resize the images on my scrollview in a ratio, which is fine I believe. The problem is When the number of images increases on the scrollview then application runs out of memory. It must be due to me using the images directly in an imageview instead of using CATiledLayer. But, I am looking for help in displaying async images on scrollview using CATiledLayer.

Many Thanks,

Reno Jones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in simple words is all I did.. I have already been downloading images async and caching them up on device, then I have added an UIImage (imageObject) property to my current tile class, which holds the image object being downloaded and then implemented the following and did the trick for me. And believe me or not, imageview loading vs CATiledLayer - CATiledLayer is 100x faster and efficient.

```
+ layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [imgObject drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
}
```

Hope it helps someone else in future. Let me know if I can be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I edit completely the answer based on the comments.

You should set a controller as delegate of the scrollview than in the scrollViewDidScroll: (or in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: if you want to check it less often) method you can check if some your images are outside the visible part of the content view and then release (i.e. set the pointer to nil) them to save some memory.

For your convenience here's an example how to get the visible part of your content:

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size;
```

everything completely outside this rect should be released (of course you then have to reload them if user scroll: it may be tricky constantly load/unload...)

Comment: Thanks for writing back, I have already been using GCD. But I am trying to display images in a irregular way, so I can't use tableview. Apparently images are of different dimensions, I reduce them in the ration which should be around 150 as its width and X as its height, then draw another image on the right side, something similar to what google image search display on screen. Images are placed one below another of irregular sizes. I will have to use CATiledLayer for this. Thanks though.

Comment: ok but then you have to "manually" dealloc images that go out of view. I guess the problem lay there: the scrollview keep all the images and then consume all the memory...

Comment: Thanks for writing back. so, what's the best way of doing it? I apparently have lots of imageviews on scrollview, should I set the image to nil of the imageviews which are currently not in the view or when user have scrolled down. what's the best way of approaching this issue? Thanks again.

Comment: But here, I am not doing pagination so I cannot unload the images as well. My images grid looks like this one - http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvhjIvdc-vVEtKsIiZBN4JlzGq5GAp4Cs6fugVV0q5ckr_wWhN2q5zC2EA

Comment: nah, thanks though. I have already done that but that's not helping my cause, so i tried implementing CATiledLayer with Async images and i've been able to do so. Thanks.